# Toggle ios7 status bar

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar

I would like to know if there is a way to hide the ios7 status bar temporarily (i.e toggle). I have scoured the internet and I can only find out how to turn it off indefinitely.

The thing being is I have one subview that I use as a full screen and unfortunately the status bar needs to be hidden in order to make the subview look cleaner.

This is the code I have found to hide the status bar.. but i have no idea how to bring it back again after hiding it.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It is actually right in the description of the method in the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW141)

> If you change the return value for this method, call the setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate method.

So just make your `prefersStatusBarHidden` method return YES or NO conditionally based on whether you want it hidden or not and call `setsNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` when you know the result will change.

example:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    if(someViewIsVisible)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```